# xpath: getting text node value without using text()

Tags: xml, xpath

I am wondering what is the purpose of using text() in xpath. If I have an xml document

```
 <book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
 </book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>
```

And I need to find the price of the books. I can use:
/bookstore/book/price[text()]  or
/bookstore/book/price

It will give me same results.  So why use text()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use `text()` in this particular case, and `text()` is often overused among XPath newbies.

There are valid use cases for the `text()` node test and they involve times when one wants to specifically target a text node.

For example, suppose that some of the books had blank prices and you wanted to get only the non-blank ones:

```
<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <price></price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Narnia</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>
```

`/bookstore/book/price` would return three elements, while `/bookstore/book/price[text()]` would return two.

Or there may be times when you want to get just an element's text nodes, and not its entire content:

```
<book category="CHILDREN">
  Harry Potter
  <author>J. K. Rowling</author>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>
```

In this case, `/bookstore/book` would produce an element whose string value is `Harry Potter    J. K. Rowling29.99`, whereas `/bookstore/book/text()` would produce a set of text nodes, the first of which has a string value of `Harry Potter`, and the other two just whitespace.

As Michael Kay points out in the comments, using `text()` can be useful when dealing with mixed content (where text nodes are side-by-side with elements as in the second example above). There should be very few cases where you need to use `text()` with non-mixed content.

Comment: If we're being precise about it, `/bookstore/book/text()` gives you a set of three nodes, the first of which has the string value newline-space-space-"Harry Potter"-nl-space-space, the second nl-space-space, and the third just one nl.

Comment: I would add that text() can be particularly useful when handling mixed content (text nodes that have elements as siblings). But in non-mixed content, it's nearly always a bad sign if you see text() used in XPath expressions.

Answer (score 0):

No, the XPath expression

```
/bookstore/book/price
```

does *not* return string values. It returns element nodes that are called "price". But the XPath environment or engine you are using (we don't know which one) automatically outputs the *string value* of those elements.

For instance, this is what happens in many contexts if XPath is used in conjunction with **XSLT**, as with the `xsl:value-of` instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="price"/>
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^   XSLT
                      ^^^^^      XPath
```

Above, the XPath expression inside XSLT returns an element node, but `xsl:value-of` only outputs the string value of this element.

In some cases, the string value of an element `price` is not the same as `price/text()`, because

> the string value of an element is the concatenation of all its *descendant* text nodes

and

> `price/text()` returns all *immediate* child text nodes of the `price` element